# Reducing the loading time in an HTML document filled with thousands of PNGs by generating thumbnail JPGs

Tags: html, png, jpeg, thumbnails

I'd like to make an HTML document with all of my own photos saved on my computer, and use it as an offline catalog, as most image viewing software (commercially available) don't satisfy my needs.

There's about 1000 photos and the vast majority of them are PNGs, about 10-15MB each.

I'm suspecting that each time I'd open this HTML document, loading would take an enormous amount of time.

To prevent that, I was told I should create thumbnail versions of those photos (e.g., 200x200px JPGs), and use them instead, while enclosing them in links that redirect me to the original locally saved PNG files.

Just asking to verify if there's any better alternative to this, or should I really go through this thumbnails solution? If there isn't, how would I mass generate those thumbnails, so I don't do it individually?

I'm on a High Sierra Mac and a Windows 7 PC.

Extra question: Should I, by any chance, use a document coded in a language other than HTML, for this purpose? For example, a language faster or more efficient or more cross-platform, that I didn't think of myself? I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, which the default Windows explorer can't do already. I mean, the software is there already, to show thumbnail icons and to display the full size image when double-clicking a thumbnail. You don't need to make the images available on the web, right?

Comment: Hi please, ask one question at a time. What is exactly your problem and what have you tried until now? You should have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back to modify your question=)

Comment: Hi jdocdp, you could try to add a limiter (a.k.a. pagination) to your page, so that only a maximum of e.g. twenty images will be shown at a time rather than a page full of images and scrolling capability. The eye can only "meet" so much and a monitor is only able to display images on one screen at a limited size and/or amount, so using such would be very viable. Thumbnails do decrease load time due to less amount of pixels required to render these images, but won't matter if you still intend to load all of them in one go.

Comment: @MrLister The default Windows explorer won't do it. I want to create a sort of Instagram-like image library for myself.

Comment: @Barrosy So I should expect a rather long loading time even if I use JPG thumbnails? Because I definitely need to load all of them in one go, so I can search the text/tags of all of them right away. Pagination wouldn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: IG uses pagination as well (when you swipe from one set collection of images to the next). It also uses the same mechanic used for loading content when scrolling down (not sure how it is called anymore, but it is a feature you might be able to apply as well).

Comment: @Barrosy You are correct, but like I said I merely want it to kind of resemble Instagram. Not *be* Instagram. Instant searchability in text and tags throughout all of the images, practically renders pagination unusable, doesn't it? Thank you for your response, by the way.

Comment: You didn't mention any text or tags in the question, only photos. This sounds like a task for a database or a spreadsheet.

Comment: @MrLister I can confirm a spreadsheet won't work. I have tried it and didn't like it. So far, an HTML document is the best solution I've come up with to build a kind of IG looking page with instant text searchability. It's just that the loading time would be a real problem, unless there's a workaround like the aforementioned JPG thumbnails.

Comment: Then why don't you just do that and see if it works for you? Nobody here can tell you if you will like a certain solution or not.

Comment: @Barrosy Can you confirm that JPG thumbnails, even though they're not full size PNGs, would still take a lot of time to load on my page? Did I get it right? :/

Comment: It depends on the amount of thumbnails you are intending to render and the size of your thumbnails. I cannot tell you because loading times depend on a lot of factors as well as the size of the files and/or images you are trying to render. There are [plenty examples](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_thumbnail.asp) available if you are looking around to see where thumbnails are being used. As you can see, some of these examples provide no problems concerning loading time.

Comment: @Barrosy I see. I'll give it a try and see for myself. Any idea how should I mass generate those thumbnails? Thanks.